# Python -- split a string with multiple occurrences of same delimiter

Tags: python, regex, string

How can I take a string that looks like this

```
string = 'Contact name: John Doe                     Contact phone: 222-333-4444'
```

and split the string on both colons? Ideally the output would look like:

```
['Contact Name', 'John Doe', 'Contact phone','222-333-4444']
```

The real issue is that the name can be an arbitrary length however, I think it might be possible to use `re` to split the string after a certain number of space characters (say at least 4, since there will likely always be at least 4 spaces between the end of any name and beginning of `Contact phone`) but I'm not that good with regex. If someone could please provide a possible solution (and explanation so I can learn), that would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: "likely always" is not really a solid qualification to program off of...

Comment: I find this to be a super helpful tool in learning about regex https://regex101.com/

Comment: I mean, I understand this isn't best coding practice, but I can't think of a more intuitive way to solve the problem. I'm parsing pdf documents and there is a line in each one that looks like the string above. The solution might be imperfect but I'm willing to live with a small margin for error for now.

edit: that link does look super helpful so I'll definitely check it out! Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re
s = 'Contact name: John Doe                     Contact phone: 222-333-4444'
new_s = re.split(':\s|\s{2,}', s)
```

Output:

```
['Contact name', 'John Doe', 'Contact phone', '222-333-4444']
```

Regex explanation:

```
:\s => matches an occurrence of ': '
| => evaluated as 'or', attempts to match either the pattern before or after it
\s{2,} => matches two or more whitespace characters
```

Comment: Can you just help me understand a bit? I know `/s` is space character and I'm guessing `{2,}` means look for this pattern at least 2 times? Still a bit confused but I'd like to understand how it works.

Comment: @J.Behnken Please see my recent edit. I added an explanation of the pattern passed to `re.split`.

Comment: Thanks @Ajax1234. That was super helpful.